# margin between Bootstrap's div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a grid with the bootstrap styles, however when I use `col-sm- *` the divs are very close together and the `shadow` effect that I put on them is lost, I have put a margin on the `div` but the last `div` is disbanded and it gets off, that's not what I had in mind, I've seen that it can be disguised with the `border` property equal to the background color of the parent `div` but that property I use for other things. I've thought about using the `outline` propierty to see if I can disguise that property so that it takes on the background color, but I still do not know how it works. I leave a snippet of how it looks without margin and with margin.

I searched on SO and a lot of posts are solved with the border property, again, I´m using border for another things.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border m-1">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner div and use padding like in snippets bellow

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-2">
      <div class="shadow p-5 bg-light border">
        COSILLAS
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-2">
      <div class="shadow p-5 bg-light border">
        COSILLAS
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-2">
      <div class="shadow p-5 bg-light border">
        COSILLAS
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a beast! Thanks hommie.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chiller.

One more solution is to change the Bootstrap's width of `col-sm-4` from

```
flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
max-width: 33.333333%;
```

to

```
flex: 0 0 32.333333%;
max-width: 32.333333%;
```

(or smaller) and set `justify-content: between` in outer `row`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  .col-sm-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 32.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 32.333333%;
    max-width: 32.333333%;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 shadow p-5 bg-light border">
      COSILLAS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```